# Problems evaluating a simple vectorial field with VectorPlot

Tags: plotting, vector, plot-themes

I'm trying to plot the electrostatic field generated from a single charge on a plane. Without the $\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}$ factor and the value of the charge $q$, as a function of $x, y$ the electric field is
$$
\vec{E}(\vec{r})\equiv\vec{E}(x,y) = \frac{\vec{r}}{|\vec{r}|^3}\equiv\begin{cases}\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
\frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\end{cases}
$$
I thought the best way to plot this plane field was the function `VectorPlot`. Here is the code I entered and the output result

```
VectorPlot[{x/((x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), y/((x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

I tried to change `x_min\x_max` and `y_min\y_max` but I got the same outcome. Why is it plotting only one vector? What am I missing?

I then decided to look at the `StreamDensityPlot`:

```
StreamDensityPlot[{x/((x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)), y/((x^2 + y^2)^(3/2))}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

The only result I got was this "purply" plot...

[image]

Now I'm a little bit confused on the use of these two plotting function, as on the mathematica documentation online it uses only simple vectorial fields such as $f(x,y) = (x,y)$ and everything looks so cool, but when I approach the basic vectorial field of physics I get only terrible results. 
Any ideas?

Comment: another possibility is `StreamPlot`, which is thought to show the direction of the field in each point, regardless of its intensity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VectorScale` can be used to take control of the amplitude.

```
f[x_, y_] := {x/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2), y/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)}
```

When close to the origin, set the `Norm` of the vector (argument `#5`) to `None`.

You may want to tweak the value, I used the radius of 0.2 corresponding to

```
Norm[f[0.2, .2]]

12.5
```

Implementing this in `VectorPlot`

```
VectorPlot[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, 
   Function[If[#5 > 12.5, None, #5]] }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]